# How can I make my Binary Tree's search/traversal method work?

Tags: python, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I just recently got done with my own implementation of a binary tree, which works pretty well for a first attempt I think. I can add left and right children to a root node fairly easily, view a node's value, as well as verify if a certain node is a child or not.

However, I do have a problem with a search function I have, which calls upon a Pre-order traversal system. In my IDE, using a binary tree like so:

[image: Simple Binary Tree]

attempting to use my search function constantly returns the error **"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'data'"**, which I'm not particularly sure what it means. In my code here:

```
def search(self, value):
    def find(x):
        if x.data is not False:
            return True

    val2 = self.traverse_pre_order(find)
    if val2 is not True:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

I attempted to change x.data to simply x, but this returns me the AttributeError **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'traverse_pre_order'**.

I've attatched a link to [PasteBin with my full code](https://pastebin.com/A2Gm5nBt) relevant to the Binary Tree I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `x.data` should be changed to `x` since you do `visit(self.data)`. Your input is already `self.data`, so `x` would be `self.data` and `x.data` would be equal to `self.data.data`, which doesn't make sense.

Second, you should change your recursion condition in `traverse_pre_order`.
It should be `if self.left is not None:` not `if hasattr(self, 'left'):`. You don't want to check if `self.left` exists (since it will always exist because you initialize it in `__init__`). Instead you should check if it is `None`.

There are also noticeable errors in structure of your `traverse_pre_order` and `search` but I guess you can try solving that yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your code:

- you define some variables right below the class definition (value, left_child, right_child), but never use them.
- Clearly think about what each method should do. Your `traverse_pre_order` function doesn't return anything, so nothing is stored in `val2` in the `search` function.

You get the errors

1. because you basically call `find(Node.data)`, and the find function then tries to do `data.data` (which doesn't exist)
2. because at the end there is a node with `left=None` and you try to call `left.traverse_pre_order()`. You should check `left not None` instead of using `hasattr`